# Сортировка TreeMap по убыванию ключа

Tags: java, сортировка

Приветствую. Никак не могу понять возможно ли TreeMap отсортировать по убыванию ключа без использования циклов и всего такого, например просто передав в нее компаратор?

Моя карта:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> returnMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>()
```

Пробовал:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> returnMap = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(new Comparator<Integer>()
        {
            @Override
            public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2)
            {
                return o2 - o1;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Передавайте [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) в конструктор.

```
 Map<Integer, String> map = new TreeMap<Integer, String>(Collections.reverseOrder());
```